# ¿Cómo sumar filas y columnas en consulta SqlServer?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta y me devuelve los campos como en la foto de abajo.

```
SELECT A.Cuenta_Id, B.EstructuraCuenta_Id, B.Cuenta, B.Descripcion, C.Periodo_Id, D.Descripcion , C.Debito, C.Credito FROM Cuenta A 
INNER JOIN EstructuraCuenta B ON A.EstructuraCuenta_Id = B.EstructuraCuenta_Id
INNER JOIN  SaldoCuenta C  ON A.Cuenta_Id = C.Cuenta_Id  
INNER JOIN  Periodo D ON  C.Periodo_Id = D.Periodo_Id WHERE C.Periodo_id >=1  AND c.Periodo_Id <= 5
GROUP BY A.Cuenta_Id, B.EstructuraCuenta_Id, B.Cuenta, B.Descripcion, C.Periodo_Id, C.Debito, C.Credito , D.Descripcion
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo si tomo la Cuenta = 11100501 me arrojaria la sumatoria de la columna Debito y la sumatoria de la columna Credito correspondientes a esta cuenta.   y la resta de esta sumatorias.

```
Cuenta          Descripcion       Debito          Credito            (Debito – Credito )
11100501    COL CTE 04054484786  584.268.251.222  531.209.177.128    -53.059.074.094
```

Comment: Por favor no uses capturas de pantalla en tus preguntas sí no son absolutamente necesarios. En vez de esto copia y pega la tabla como texto formateado en tu pregunta.

Comment: No estoy seguro de cual sea tu pregunta ¿Por qué tienes un GROUP BY? ¿Cómo quieres sumar? ¿Cuál es la lógica o regla de negocio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que no sabes que significa `GROUP BY`. `GROUP BY x, y, z` dice "quiero una fila por x, y, z en el resultado". Tú quieres una fila por cuenta, entonces quieres `GROUP BY Cuenta_Id`.

Si usas `GROUP BY Cuenta_Id, Debito, Credito`, te quedas con las filas originales (con la excepción de que si hay dos filas con el mismo Debito y Credito por una cuenta, recibes una sola fila en vez de las dos con Debito y Credito duplicados).

Bueno, quieres mostrar una fila por cuenta y también muestras información de su estructura. Pero, ¿el ID y la descripción de su periodo? ¿De que periodo estás hablando? Una cuenta puede tener más de un periodo. Tienes que decidir cuál periodo quieres mostrar. ¿El mínimo o el máximo quizás? Puede que no quieres mostrar no periodo en absoluto ;-)

Pues, ahora que tienes la explicación, hay que mencionar que SQL Server no permite un solo `GROUP BY Cuenta_Id` si quieres mostrar su estructura. Esto parece raro, porque muestras una fila por cuenta y una cuenta tiene una sola estructura. ¿Qué es el problema de SQL Server en esta situación? El asunto se llama "dependencia funcional". La estructura depende de la cuenta. Pero SQL Server no es capaz de detectar esa dependencia y así no respeta esta regla del SQL Standard. Recibirías un mensaje como "Msg 8120 Level 16 State 1 Line 1 Column 'B.Descripcion' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause".

Entonces hay que eludir esta debilidad del SQL Server. Una manera es tener estas columnas en el `GROUP BY` (por ejemplo `GROUP BY Cuenta_Id, B.Descripcion`), otra es aplicar una función de agregación inoperante para estas columnas (por ejemplo `MIN(B.Descripcion)`). Y hay una opción más, y esta prefiero. En vez de join todos los saldos, para agregar los datos después, agrega los saldos *antes* de join, para join los saldos *sumados*.

Por fin, claro que necesitas la funciona `SUM` que falta en tu consulta completamente ;-)

La consulta que recomiendo:

```
SELECT
  c.cuenta_id,
  ec.estructuracuenta_id,
  ec.cuenta,
  ec.descripcion,
  sc.debito_total,
  sc.credito_total
FROM cuenta c
INNER JOIN estructuracuenta ec on ec.estructuracuenta_id = c.estructuracuenta_id
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT cuenta_id, SUM(debito) AS debito_total, SUM(credito) AS credito_total
  FROM saldocuenta
  WHERE periodo_id BETWEEN 1 AND 5
  GROUP BY cuenta_id
) sc ON sc.cuenta_id = s.cuenta_id 
ORDER BY c.cuenta_id;
```